# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.50' (I couldn't understand other posts on this)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot input a decimal as it comes up with this error

I've tried putting "float" function in different places

```
def Change():
  Money = int(input("How Much Money Do You Want To Change For Cash? - "))
  CoinType = int(input("What Type Of Coin Do You Want To Change Into? (1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01) - "))
  float(CoinType)
  if CoinType == 1:
    print("You Will Get", Money / CoinType,"Coins")
  if CoinType == 0.50:
    print("You Will Get", Money / CoinType,"Coins")
```

It should come up with "You will get", Money / CoinType, "Coins"

Comment: Try `float` in place of `int`

Comment: sidenote: do not store currency in floats. use the smallest denomination and ints. (so, 100 instead of 1, and 1 instead of 0.01). Convert at the end if really needed.  Because [floats have their problems.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting `int` input whereas you instruct your user to pass a `float` value in the following line:

```
CoinType = int(input("What Type Of Coin Do You Want To Change Into? (1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01) - "))
```

Therefore, changing it to `float` should fix the problem:

```
CoinType = float(input("What Type Of Coin Do You Want To Change Into? (1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01) - "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `float`

```
CoinType = float(input("What Type Of Coin Do You Want To Change Into? (1.00, 0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01) - "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float` in place of `int`. Integers (`int`) will not accommodate any decimal